Who qualifies as a bodhisattva?
Does a person cultivating bodhicitta qualify as a bodhisattva? Or to qualify as a bodhisattva, does one need to have levelled-up to some degree in the perfection of the great perfections.
I have seen/heard this discussed before, but it was a while ago and I can't remember where I would find the references.
I'm not sure any answers to this question would have a major impact on the actual application of cultivating bodhicitta, but I would enjoy exploring the concepts around it.
This is my first question on Stack Exchange, so I am open to feedback about whether the format and content of my question is suitable for this forum.

Question format is perfect. Better than a lot of new users I have seen before. Better than the ramblings I write when i ask a question too.

Thanks for your feedback, @Remyla. I do enjoy a good ramble now and then, and am also looking forward to how Stack Exchange seems to encourage and reward brevity and concision.

On one occasion I attended a lecture by Geshe Ngawang Samten at the Vajrayana Institute in Sydney Australia. I recall the Geshe explain:

The term 'Hinayana' refers to practising to realize Emptiness for the liberation/sake of one's own mind.

The term 'Mahayana' refers to the practice of Bodhicitta, which is practising or acting for the liberation/sake of others.

The term 'Vajrayana' refers to the practice of developing the outer beautiful qualities of a Deity.


In the Theravada Pali Suttas, the original term 'Bodhisatta' was exclusively reserved for the unawakened Buddha-To-Be, meaning 'seeker of Awakening'. For example, in SN 12.10 or in MN 19.
In Mahayana, the impression is the term 'Bodhisattva' refers to those practising Bodhicitta. I recall the Geshe saying the Hinayana path is a prerequisite for Bodhicitta; that it will be difficult to help liberate others if one's own mind is not liberated. In other words, it appears in Mahayana (in contrast to Theravada), the Bodhisattva must have developed the Great Perfections to some degree.
Some teachings by Geshe Samten about 'Bodhisattva' are at this link.

Bodhisattva is a being who achieved personal Nirvana (Arahat level), but chose to continue rebirth in Samsara to save other beings.
If a being has not reached Nirvana, they cannot reliably direct others toward it, since you cannot teach what you don't know.
It can be said that a person cultivating bodhicitta is on the path to becoming Bodhisattva somewhere in the future. If we were to call everyone on this path a Bodhisattva, then it would lead to a lot of confusion, both when reading Buddhist texts, and when distinguishing between highly advanced and beginner practitioners.

Greetings. I wonder if you are sure this is correct? As far as I am aware, a Bodhisattva/Bodhisatta can not be an arahant. They have the parami that they could be easily, but they have put off their own enlightenment for the sake of others. Once one enters the path of enlightenment ie sottapana, only 7 lives maximum remain until full enlightenment. What makes a Bodhisatta, is the determination in the presence of another Buddha, with enough good merit. Thus they will have the prediction of their future Buddhahood & start developing the parimi in their long journey for the welfare of all beings.

@Bhikkhu111 it might not be the common definition of the term Bodhisattva, but I'm 100% sure that a person cannot really save anyone (guide to Nirvana), if they haven't reached Nirvana themselves. In other words, becoming Arahat is a pre-requisite for becoming a Bodhisattva.

Greetings @HermanNurlygayanov well certainly from the Theravada view, this is incorrect. I did read in a mayahaya sutta once that venerable Sariputta relinquished his aspiration for enlightenment to be a Buddha in the future.  As he was a sottapana and a great disciple of a Buddha, it does not make any sense to me? I found this sutra https://www.cttbusa.org/vajrasutra/vs9.html which show the existence of path and fruit.

@
HermanNurlygayanov are you possibly confusing the determination for Buddhahood under a Buddha as enlightenment? I think one Mahayana school has 52 stages of a Bodhisattva, only the last stage is full enlightenment of Buddhahood. Do you know any references to clarify this? These are still profound beings that could of realised nibbana easily, but they put of that end of suffering for the welfare of others.

A person becomes a bodhisattva when one experiences what is known as engaging or directing Bodhicitta.
Bodhicitta has 2 forms or levels if you will.
First form is aspiring Bodhicitta.
So in general it is a wish or a (virtuous) desire to attain liberation (become a Buddha) and lead others to liberation.
Second form is engaging, or directing Bodhicitta.
This is rather the actual journey one takes, or is taking towards liberation (becoming a buddha)
So the difference being that the 1st form is "just" a desire to gain liberation (for the benefit of others) the second form is the mental phenomena or drive that led one to be already on the path to liberation, with the intention of becoming a buddha to help others to liberation.
Having this 2nd form of Bodhicitta as a mental phenomena makes one a Bodhisattva.
I would suppose having aspiring Bodhicitta is akin to aspiring to become a Bodhisattva.
Technically I could be a Bodhisatvva, I have experienced the latter form, though I have gave up the Mahayana myself as I feel it is fruitless.
I am explaining this only for clarity regarding the Mahayana definition of a Bodhisattva.
Like someone pointed out already, in the actual Buddhas teachings the term was reserved for the unawakened Buddha, Siddhartha Gautama and his previous incarnations in jataka tales.
Now somewhere along the line Mahayana have created some devices regarding gaining the desire to become liberated not for oneself, but for the benefit of others. Bodhicitta.
Sure it makes sense as the Buddha himself by his own words explained that he saw the previous Buddha in a past life and then gained the aspiration to become a Buddha himself.
The difference is that the Buddha didn't actually say he did it for others at all. Mahayana have just made it up I guess.
In reality Buddha probably did it for himself, as per the classic "zero story" of his life (seeing the 3 signs of samsara and renouncing into solitude)
When he was awakened, became a Buddha, he was not even going to teach anyone! until (it is said) he was directed by some gods (ishvara or brahma) and he saw there were some people with "little dust in their eyes" that could understand the truth, so he set forth and taught the path to liberation.
Can you see the contradiction?
Mahayanists claim Buddha did it for the benefit of all, but he himself said he was contemplating not even teaching anyone. Doesn't sound like the call signs of someone who has Bodhicitta.
Then to the forms of Bodhicitta. Form is an aggregate, it is just a mental factor, empty phenomena like any other. Something myself eventually came to an understanding of what I once thought was a highly revered mindstate.
As per sunyata, form is empty (heart sutra)
Only jhana/dhyana is a mental factor worth venerating. (my own opinion) because higher levels of jhana can lead one to be reborn in pure lands, more pure than this human form, where one can attain liberation.
The ultimate crux too is that all dependant related phenomena is impermanent. Bodhicitta is clearly dependently related. it is a mental concept and a mental phenomena, mental factor. It depends upon the mind itself. So Bodhicitta gained or experienced in this life doesn't necessary stay with us in a next life, or we may even lose it in this life. The only experiences that will stay with us throughout rebirths are the experiences we had of nibbana on the path. So once one becomes a sotapanna, one will not lose this experience in future lives. Enlightenment is guaranteed (within 7 lives) This requires some level of jhana, not Bodhicitta!
Lastly we can quote the Buddha himself, I wont post lots of passages but simply in MN 115 Buddha says that it's both impossible for  2 Buddhas to be in the same world system at the same time, as too it is impossible for a woman to become a Buddha (more that a Buddha would only be reborn into the form of a man).
I am pointing this out because in mahayana sects they make no distinction between the differing karma of man and woman humans and they think and teach that we can all become Buddhas by gaining Bodhicitta, realizing emptiness then we are Buddhas. Even women.
When reality is that Buddhas only exist in the world when there is no dharma in it. Only 1 Buddha can exist in the world at a time, and only great Buddhas ever come into being in extremely long periods, and that the next Buddha, Matreya, is already in a pure land as a sakadagami (once returner)
Now this is not to say that one cannot become a Buddha in a different world, realm or time, but what it does mean is if one strives for Bodhicitta one cannot become a Buddha in this life and by virtue of following the lasts Buddhas teaching, ones enlightenment would be an arhants enlightenment (hearers enlightenment) and not a Buddhas enlughtenment. Difference of course is that Buddhas find their own way and arhants follow what a Buddha found and taught. Then you also have solitary Buddhas who don't teach, but they too only come into being when there is no dharma in the world.
So by logic one (a Bodhisattva) must postpone their own liberation to wait for a chance to become a Buddha, as gaining a hearers enlightenment and becoming an arhant here will mean no more rebirth, no rebirth and one cannot become a a Buddha. Again flawed logic.
Though there is a rudely disrespectful piece of literature in Tibetan Buddhism (Mahayana) written by Milarepas student, Gampompa, that says that arhants were not actually enlightened and that they still have work to do to become a Buddha but Buddha himself basically lied to them, tricked them... Which by logic would mean that Buddha didn't actually teach the path to liberation and none of his students ever gained nirvana.
Very rude teaching that actually the vast majority of Tibetan sects believe to be completely true and teachings of the Buddha, just not via THE Buddhas mouth, but by (Gampompas) Buddha nature.
This is why I find faulty logic in not just the concept of Bodhicitta taught by the Mahayana, but the entirety of the Mahayana itself. Among many other faults in logic not suitable for this thread.
Personally I am inclined to take a more neutral stance on the mindstate. I think it is actually a good mindstate to cultivate as a beginner when one is trying to logically refute the teachings to find the truth of them. Plus it helps build one compassion which when perfected will lead one to better states of existence, Brahmavihara. Then when one attains engaging Bodhicitta, like any other useless mindstate, I think we should abandon it. Something that is not permitted in vajrayana as a mandatory vow one needs to create is to never abandon Bodhicitta.
Still with the engaging Bodhicitta, one is already a Bodhisatvva, one is already on the path to gaining liberation, so one should no longer be concerned with cultivating Bodhicitta.
As for what engaging Bodhicitta is and how to distinguish the 2 forms. I think it is probably inexplicable to correctly discriminate the 2, one has to discriminate them in ones own mind oneself but a good study or systematic understanding is that (I have found) it parallels the distinction between piti and sukha.
One is a psychosomatic feeling, the other a mental experience.
Same with the 2 Bodhicittas but Bodhicitta is not a feeling. Though they can lead to pleasure, sukha.
Aspiring is a mental idea, desire, wish, engaging is a conviction, determination, realization.
Best I can do to explain it I think.
Even more simpler childish analogy is that aspiring is like wanting to get on a bus, engaging is being on the bus.

Long reply but I thought most of this was actually really required to get the ideas of not just what Bodhicitta or a Bodhisattva is, but the reasons behind the concepts.

I appreciate the detail, @remyla. I knew the theory around this was complicated, but your comment shows me there is a lot remaining for me to explore. I also appreciate having my attachment to Mahayana teachings about bodhicitta challenged.

I am not trying to disparage you from the mahayana path, just I want to say that if you look at it logically, there are countless faulty logic in that sect. Many ex mahayanists have moved towards a theravada journey. The latter being based upon logic and empirical evidence rather that faith and mysticism. Not that every theravada sect is without cultural nonsense.

There is no intrinsic compassion involved on this planet. Compassion needs to be developed. Compassion is the benchmark of Boddisattva. To develop it one should give up all attachments and hatred like a true monk. The extent of compassion goes as far as if someone cuts your limbs then you should not have a bad or cruel thought against him or her.

Since I am keen to find an answer to this question myself I have over the years studied the following book.
Who qualifies as a bodhisattva? is answered by the following text by Shantideva.
My personal experience with the text "A Guide to the Bodhisattva Way of Life"
by Shantideva, is an ongoing one.
Translated from the Sanskrit and the Tibetan by Vesna A. Wallace and B. Alan Wallace. Snow Lion Publications.
The authors draw from both Sanskrit and Tibetan translations.
If one can do everything listed in this book, then one qualifies as a bodhisattva.

Well I understand this is not asking the Theravada school position but as both schools have Master Gotama as their founder I guess it will relate.
To become a bodhisatta, one must build up enough good kamma to be able to, as a man, in the presence of another Buddha, mentally (or I guess verbally) make that aspiration. That Buddha at that time will then use the Dhamma Eye to look into the future, and declare if it will happen or not. The same applies to right and left hand disciples of a Buddha as described here.
So any being with enough merit can determine to be a Buddha in the future. I feel the path only truly begins though once the determination occurs in the presence of a Buddha, and the prediction is made, as that is the point, it becomes impossible to alter the path.
Before then, a being could still relinquish their determination and realise Nibbana earlier.
Mind you, the Dhammapada says that being a Buddha is the difficult path. The time of the last 27 Buddhas is immeasurably long in this world system and countless aeons that have passed of expansion and contraction, evolutions and universal cessation.
Thus Buddhas teach to end suffering, so higher determination is up to the indiviual.
